# Why is drawing contours not working in image after erosion and dilation?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, contour

I have and portrait image. To which I:

1. Convert to Grayscale
2. Then convert to binary
3. Then I used morphological erosion operation.
4. Then I used morphological dilation operation.

Now, as last process, I am trying to find out the contours and drawing them. However, contours are getting found and drawn too, but, it is only getting drawn in white color, which made it looked like, contours is not drawn at all. What am I doing wrong??

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2


img = cv2.imread("Test1.jpg")
image = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.imshow("GrayScaled", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)

ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(image, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
cv2.imshow("Black&White", thresh)
cv2.waitKey(0)

kernel1 = np.ones((2,2),np.uint8)
erosion = cv2.erode(thresh,kernel1,iterations = 4)
cv2.imshow("AfterErosion", erosion)
cv2.waitKey(0)

kernel2 = np.ones((1,1),np.uint8)
dilation = cv2.dilate(erosion,kernel2,iterations = 5)
cv2.imshow("AfterDilation", dilation)
cv2.waitKey(0)

contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(dilation, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
cv2.drawContours(dilation, contours, -1, (255, 0, 0), 2)
cv2.imshow("Contours", dilation)
cv2.waitKey(0)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Here are images step by step:

Original Image:

[image: Original Image]

GrayScaled Image:

[image: GrayScaled]

Binary Image:

[image: Binary]

After Erosion:

[image: Erosion]

After Dilation:

[image: Dilation]

Contour:

[image: Contours]

I am defining the color of the contours boundary to be red in above code. So, why is it not showing red boundaries??

Comment: Draw contours on a color image! Convert grayscale dilation to the RGB

Comment: Maybe post a short selfanswer and the last image with the red contour :) thanks for making a nice question. They are few in between.